# Merge Duplicate Accounts in Salesforce through SOAP request in Python

Tags: python, xml, soap, salesforce

I am currently trying to merge two Accounts in salesforce using the following code snippets. However, I keep getting a response 500. Can someone please point me to the error I am doing when defining the body of the XML request.
This is the current implementation.

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import requests

def connect_sf(security_token, password, username):
    sf = Salesforce(username, password,
                   security_token)
   return sf

sf = connect_sf()

headers = { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml', 'Accept': 'application/soap+xml,application/dime, multipart/related, text/*', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sf.session_id, 'SOAPAction': 'merge', 'Sforce-Auto-Assign': 'false', 'charset':'UTF-8'}


master_id = 'MASTERID'
victim_id = 'VICTIMID'

body = f"""


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"
    xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<soapenv:Body> 
 
   <ns1:merge>   
<ns1:masterRecord>    
  <masterRecord xsi:type="sobject:Account" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   {master_id}
   </ns1:masterRecord>
   <ns1:recordToMergeIds>
   {victim_id}
   </ns1:recordToMergeIds> 
   </ns1:merge>

"""

session = requests.Session() 
sf.session.request(method = 'POST', url = 'https://' + sf.sf_instance +'/services/Soap/u/' + sf.sf_version, data = body, headers = headers)
```

Thank you for your help ^^

Answer (score 0):

Three issues.

First, you're trying to use Authorization header with SOAP; this is incorrect.

Second, you've missed part of your payload; in XML, each opening tag must have a closing tag.

Third, you missed some XML namespaces, which can cause issues.

I've copy-pasted some source from another example, and came up with the following modification:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import requests

def connect_sf(security_token, password, username):
    sf = Salesforce(username, password,
                security_token)
return sf

sf = connect_sf()

headers = { 
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml', 
    'Accept': 'application/soap+xml,application/dime, multipart/related, text/*', 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sf.session_id, 
    'SOAPAction': 'merge', 
    'Sforce-Auto-Assign': 'false', 
    'charset':'UTF-8'
}


master_id = 'MASTERID'
victim_id = 'VICTIMID'

body = f"""

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Header>
        <n1:SessionHeader xmlns:n1="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" env:mustUnderstand="0">
            <n1:sessionId>REDACTED</n1:sessionId>
        </n1:SessionHeader>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <n2:merge xmlns:n2="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
            <n2:masterRecord xmlns:n3="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xsi:type="n3:Lead">
                <n3:Id>{master_id}</n3:Id>
            </n2:masterRecord>
            <n2:recordToMergeIds>{victim_id}</n2:recordToMergeIds>
        </n2:merge>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
"""

session = requests.Session() 
sf.session.request(method = 'POST', url = 'https://' + sf.sf_instance +'/services/Soap/u/' + sf.sf_version, data = body, headers = headers)
```

There may be additional issues, but these are the minimum changes you'll need.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox. However, I am still getting the 500 error. Can you point me to the sources you used to define the xml body?

Comment: @SalmaBouzid I originally copied from a post I can't find, but [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-soap-api-sample-wsdls.html) is an official resource you can use.